# Obtain a single TOC from using both listings and SASnRdisplay

Tags: listings

I began using LaTeX just yesterday and I'm stuck on a frustrating problem. I need to automatically include a lot of source code into my document and getting it code-highlighted, row-numbered, labeled and indexed. I've done most of the job, except few points. First of all, I'm using different languages: PHP, JS, PostgreSQL, R and SAS. I've found that `listings` doesn't correctly treat `/**/` SAS comments, so I decided to use the `SASnRdisplay` package which seems to be a sort of "extension" of the `listings` package. They share a lot of aspects. After a lot of tricking I finally got satisfied with the results.

What I need to do now is creating a list of listings containing the references to the listings generated by `listings` and the listings generated by `SASnRdisplay` using a single common numeration. At the moment I have basically two numberings: the `listings` numbering and the `SASnRdisplay` numbering.

I've tried using
`\setcounter{lstlisting}{3}`
but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example to test the `\lstlistoflistings` command (the other features are not implemented here for simplicity):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{SASnRdisplay}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP, caption=First listing - using package ``listings'']
    $var = "value";
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, caption=Second listing - using package ``listings'']
    console.log('0123456789');
\end{lstlisting}



\begin{Rcode}[caption=Third listing - using package ``SASnRdisplay'']
    df <- c(1,2,3)
\end{Rcode}


\begin{SAScode}[caption=Fourth listing - using package ``SASnRdisplay'']
    /* comment */
    PROC PRINT data=mydata; VAR v1; RUN;
\end{SAScode}



\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

And here's the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Probably this can be solved by knowing the counter name used by SASnRdisplay. The other solution should be something like "unifying" the two counters, which is more complex than just incrementing/updating one of them. So my question goes in this direction.. but probably there's something else that I'm ignoring.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the [source code](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/sasnrdisplay/SASnRdisplay.sty) of the `SASnRdisplay` package. It defines a macro called `\SNRletcountercounter` that overrides the normal numbering scheme of listings carried out by the `listings` package:

```
% This is inspired from the memoir class, it enables us to alias the
% listings counter such that we can have different series
% It will locally make one counter behave like another counter
% it also handles the \the<counter>
\newcommand*{\SnRletcountercounter}[2]{%
   \csletcs{c@#1}{c@#2}
   \csletcs{the#1}{the#2}
   \SnRHrefNumber{#2}
}
```

Redefining `\SNRletcountercounter` to `\@gobbletwo` cancels the effects of that macro and yields the desired output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{SASnRdisplay}
\makeatletter
\let\SnRletcountercounter\@gobbletwo
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP, caption=First listing - using package ``listings'']
    $var = "value";
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, caption=Second listing - using package ``listings'']
    console.log('0123456789');
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{Rcode}[caption=Third listing - using package ``SASnRdisplay'']
    df <- c(1,2,3)
\end{Rcode}

\begin{SAScode}[caption=Fourth listing - using package ``SASnRdisplay'']
    /* comment */
    PROC PRINT data=mydata; VAR v1; RUN;
\end{SAScode}

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jubobs! In the meanwhile I've found an alternative solution which works too. I also had a look to the original source code and I've found the name of the SASnRdisplay counter. You can set it to the current value of the lstlisting counter "on the fly". If the first SASnRdisplay code was R you need to call this:
`\setcounter{Rcode}{\value{lstlisting}}`
otherwise if it was a SAS code you need to call this:
`\setcounter{SAScode}{\value{lstlisting}}`

Comment: EDIT: your solution works but generates a problem. Before every caption of each SASnRdisplay listing in my document LaTeX generates a string stating "lstlistingRcode". I think I'll go with the counter solution because it doesn't generate any sort of problem..

Comment: @pietrop See my edit.

Comment: It generates the following error (in my document I define several commands):
`! LaTeX Error: Command \@ already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \newcommand{\@annoAccademico}{2013/2014}`

Comment: @pietrop I don't get any error. You've probably forgotten the surrounding `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; those are important.

Comment: @pietrop Did my last comment help?

Comment: Sorry @Jubobs, I was very busy in these days. I didn't forget to put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` so I can't figure out why I get that error. I solved removing the declaration of the command that caused the error because it was a surplus, but for the moment I prefer using the counter approach (incrementing the counter when needed).

Answer (score 0):

Jubobs solution (`\let\SnRletcountercounter\relax`) works but a string stating "lstlistingRcode" may appear before every listing generated by SASnRdisplay.
The other way to go is to update the listings counter using the last counter value used.
If the last listing was from the `listings` package and you want to add a listing from the `SASnRdisplay` package, then add the following line between the two listings:
`\setcounter{Rcode}{\value{lstlisting}}`
otherwise add the following one:
`\setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{Rcode}}`

If `Rcode` doesn't work try using `SAScode`.